# Is this thread safe? localThreadVar = ++atomicGlobalVar

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to iterate over a vector using its index, by multi-threads, and I would like to know if the following lines do the job correctly (my concern is thread safety issue). In other words, is *counter* guaranteed to get the value of *atomicVar* before *atomicVar* is increased by other threads?

```
static std::atomic<int> atomicVar = 0;

Threaded_Function()
{
    int size = myVector.Size();
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter= ++atomicVar, counter <= size ){                  
      auto element = myVector [counter - 1];
      // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the order of assignment to the local counter variable (that is not shared between threads) matter, if the source 'atomicVar' sequence is (supposedly) incremented atomically among all threads? If the fundamental question is "will myVector be accessed sequentially" then  no, that is *not* guaranteed even if there was a guarantee over the assignment itself.

Comment: OK, I added the definition of atomicVar. I never mentioned the order matters! I just want to make sure all elements are visited at the end.

Comment: on a side note, it would be more idiomatic to write `counter = atomicVar++, counter < size` and respectively, `myVector[counter]`.

Comment: I am not good at C++ but I thought it would not be threadsafe. Since the assignment, which is not guaranteed to be threadsafe, is done first.

Comment: @MattMan: There's no assignment to the atomic variable here. Even if there were, assignment to an atomic variable (and other operations like `++`) is threadsafe. That's the whole point of `atomic`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: What I was told is that when counter= atomicVar++ is used, the assignment is processed first, so two threads might assign the same value to their counter variable.

Comment: @MattMan: No, both assign the result of `++atomicVar` to their local variable. The result comes from an atomic update of the shared variable, so will be different for each thread.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: But  TheParamagneticCroissant was suggesting using counter= atomicVar++ instead of  ++atomicVar  and I was wondering if that one is also threadsafe.

Comment: @MattMan: Both are equally threadsafe. The suggestion was to use `atomicVar++` to simplify the code by getting the value you actually want, not the value after incrementing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I understood that it was suggested for simplification, I was not just sure if it was threadsafe. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

This is the whole point of `std::atomic`.

The `operator++()` call is made atomically, and the atomically-returned result is a temporary that belongs only to your thread. That temporary can take as long as it likes getting into `counter`: it's not shared data.

---

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith:

> `operator++()`
>   Performs atomic pre-increment. Equivalent to `fetch_add(1)+1`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add:

> Atomically replaces the current value with the result of arithmetic addition of the value and arg. The operation is read-modify-write operation.
>
> Return value: The value of the atomic variable before the call.

Notice how the `+1` takes place on the local, non-shared temporary that's initialised from the atomically-obtained initial value.

Comment: "Yes" depends on how the last sentence in the question is taken, which was poor wording from the start. The increment and decrement operators (over the atomic value) are themselves atomic units - but only in isolation, and independently of the following assignment.

Comment: @user2864740: Granted, but I think we can safely assume the OP's intent in this case.